# How to count all rows for all pages of a rad grid in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik-grid, radgridview

I am having RadGrid in my aspx page. It contains AllowPaging="true" and PageSize="5". RadGrid contain one column i.e Amount. I want to calculate total amount entered in all rows using javascript.

Below is my Javascript which I have written:

```
function Amount() {

            var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid.ClientID %>');

            var masterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();

            var row = masterTable.get_dataItems().length;

            var Amount;
            var totalAmount=0;
            for (var i = 0; i < row ; i++) {
                Amount=masterTable.get_dataItems()[i].findControl("txtSumInsured").get_value();
                totalAmount = totalAmount + Amount;
            }

        }
```

Problem I am facing is "row" holds value for 1st page only i.e 5. If my grid consists of 10 rows divided into two pages (5 rows each) then also row holds value 5.

Can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No that's not possible because you are writing a client side code thus it is able to access only those values which is present in the _DOM_. Your second page is not present in the DOM so you won't be able to calculate the amount.

Comment: True, Any other way? Like in cs page we make AllowPaging=false then ReBind() then we loop it to get all rows then after that again AllowPaging=true and rebind(). In the same or any other way can we achieve it in client side?

Comment: The bottom line is when you are calculating the amount at client side you should have the data in the _DOM_ so you need to store it in a hidden variable or something. Why not sum it up at the server side itself?

Comment: @ShadaabKhan did you try doing the same technique in JavaScript? Setting AllowPaging to false?